# How ISSetup.dll is used in InstallShield?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I notice that every time I rebuild my InstallShield project the file `PROJECT_ASSISTANT\Interm\ISSetup.dll` is updated. As described in the [documentation](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield16helplib/ISSetup-dll.htm), it executes InstallScript custom actions.

I always deliver a single exe `PROJECT_ASSISTANT\SINGLE_EXE_IMAGE\DiskImages\DISK1\Setup.exe` to my customers, and the installation runs smoothly without this ISSetup.dll.

So is this ISSetup.dll packed into the single setup.exe somehow? If not, how the Installscripts are executed on client machine?

I would like to tell you the project type (be a Basic MSI, InstallScript, or InstallScript MSI), but since I build my project from command-line (InstallShield 2012 SpringSP1 SAB) and am not able to open the project in GUI mode to view the properties pane, I don't know how to get this information from an .ism (XML format) file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forget the exact mechanics of where the file is included in each project type that may use it (sometimes it's directly in `setup.exe`, sometimes it's indirect). Regardless, `ISSetup.dll` is always the compiled InstallScript engine (the C++ part), and often has the compiled `setup.inx` (InstallScript part) "streamed" onto it. Something (perhaps setup.exe, perhaps a Windows Installer custom action) calls into it to run InstallScript code that we provided, or that you wrote.

So the short answer to the original question is: yes.

To answer the unasked questions, the `Interm` folder is an intermediate folder used for staging some of the files that get built into `setup.exe` or into the .msi file, and `ISSetup.dll` definitely receives updated compiled script code for each build of a Basic MSI or InstallScript MSI that includes custom actions.

Comment: Yes, this answers my unasked question. I don't want to back up ISSetup.dll and several other files to SVN but I was not sure if I could ignore them, now I know they are intermediate.

Comment: I've always seen ISSetup.dll in the Binary table and it exports functions such as those used by the Setup Files / SUPPORTDIR pattern.

Comment: I think ISSetup.dll would always need to be in the Binary table to support running from an admin-image installation point (not sure how well Installscript MSI works here - I avoid the project type). I have updated my answer with a Dependency Walker screen shot from an older ISSetup.dll file. In earlier versions of Installshield an Installscript runtime was required, but I think this was changed or fixed in version 12.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the **ISSetup.dll** is compiled into the **MSI's binary table** and extracted as part of the launching of the msi via msiexec.exe - at least for Basic MSI files.

The **setup.exe** wrapper probably contains the whole ISSetup.dll - perhaps statically linked or embedded somehow. **[Michael Uhrman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89999/michael-urman)** (**Installshield developer**) will probably comment if he sees this question.

---

**UPDATE**:

I found a version of this **ISSetup.dll** file, see a screen shot from **Dependency Walker** below. In addition to the exported functions seen, there are also COM register and unregister methods exported (DllRegisterServer, DllUnregisterServer, DllCanUnloadNow, DllGetClassObject). The f-functions must be the various Installscript functions. The first 5 functions must be related to Installscript MSI.

[image]